# How can I use an iperf output and only grep Interval and Bandwidth?

Tags: grep, awk, iperf

I am trying to get the output from the command

```
iperf -c 10.0.0.1 -t 3600 -i 2
```

And only need the Interval and bandwidth fields listed for the entire hour of logging.

I haven't used grep or awk in years upon years.

Help would be awesome!

Sample Output:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to node2, TCP port 5001
TCP window size:  129 KByte (WARNING: requested  130 KByte)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  3] local <IP Addr node1> port 2530 connected with <IP Addr node2> port 5001
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  0.0-10.0 sec  19.7 MBytes  15.8 Mbits/sec
```

Desired Output:

```
0.0-10.0 15.8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based solely on your posted `iperf` output, you would simply print fields 3 and 4 from the last line:

```
| awk 'END{print $3" "$7}'
```

**BUT** this question is not simply about `awk`.

**Question:**
Let's start by explaining what your `iperf` command does, for the benefit of those who are not familiar with it.

- `-c 10.0.0.1` connects to server listening at address `10.0.0.1`
- `-t 3600` keeps running for `3600` seconds, i.e. 1 hour
- `-i 2` prints a report every `2` seconds

During the next hour, a line like this is printed (added) on screen every two seconds:

```
[  3]  0.0-10.0 sec  19.7 MBytes  15.8 Mbits/sec
```

What you want is reduce the information printed on screen every two seconds, to lines of the form:

```
0.0-10.0 15.8
```

**Answer:** To obtain this, you pipe the output to `awk`:

```
iperf -c 10.0.0.1 -t 3600 -i 2 | awk '/[0-9]]/{sub(/.*]/,"");print $1" "$5}'
```

You can stop reading here if you employ `iperf`, i.e. iperf 2.

---

If you use **`iperf3`**, you should have found out by now that the piped output gets buffered. This means you do **not** see a new line printed on screen every two seconds! Instead, a whole bunch of lines gets printed every 50 seconds or so, depending on the system. Note that this does not happen with iperf 2 because it flushes the output after printing each line.

To have a line of the desired form printed on screen at the desired interval, you need **`--forceflush`**:

> ```
>    --forceflush
>           force flushing output at every interval.  Used to avoid  buffer-
>           ing when sending output to pipe.
> ```

**Answer:**

```
iperf3 -c 10.0.0.1 -t 3600 -i 2 --forceflush | awk '/[0-9]]/{sub(/.*]/,"");print}'
```

Note that this option was added to `iperf3` version `3.1.5`.